# Star Graphs and Paths between nonadjacent edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Say we have a star graph with one central vertex, with degree $n-1$, and the other $n-1$ remaining vertices are leaves in the star graph.
How many paths of length 2 are there such that we do not count the cases where 2 edges are adjacent in the diagram?

I have figured out:
For example, if $n=4$ , we have one central vertex and 3 outer vertices.  We would have 0 correct cases because all edges in the star graph are adjacent.

if $n = 5$, we would have 2 cases, paths of length 2 between the diagonals since they have other edges between them.

Could anyone explain how to continue counting such instances? For self-study on graph theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's count the number of paths of size 2  between two different leaves: ${n-1}\choose{2}$ and the number of paths of size 2 with adjacent edges: $n-1$.

Finally we have ${{n-1}\choose{2}} - n + 1$ paths.